# I can't Install Oracle J2EE JDK

Tags: installation, java, troubleshooting, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing J2EE under Ubuntu x64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187206/installing-j2ee-under-ubuntu-x64)

I can't install Oracle JDK J2EE like i show in the pix below

[image: installing failure]

this is my java (Oracle J2SE JDK) configuration

[image: java-configuration]

when I typed which java, terminal showed this

[image: which java]

How should I do? I'm very pleased for your help. sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

It can be seen that you have JDK installed, but are you sure that JDK's `bin` directory is included in `$PATH`? Do a quick check with `jar` or `javac`.

As `java` is also present in JRE's directory(`/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/bin/`) it'll show up but it cannot package new jar files. You'll be needing `jar` utility for that task, as in here. `jar` only comes in JDK's directory, so you need to include JDK's directory i.e. `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/bin/` to `$PATH`. To do that add the following line to `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile`:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/bin`

then logout and retry.

Comment: thank you. but, how do I check them?

how to add some lines to /etc/profile?

Comment: @obysr Just type those commands(`jar` or `javac`) in a terminal window. If they are present in `$PATH` they will show their usage. alternatively you can type `echo $PATH` to see it's current state. the directories under `$PATH` will be separated with `:`. To add text to `/etc/profile` use `sudo gedit /etc/profile` and for `~/.profile` use `gedit ~/.profile`

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solving. The problem locates in my machine. My Ubuntu is 64-bit machine and so is my JRE. J2EE SDK can't run on JRE 64-bit. the solving just install both of them, 32-bit and 64-bit version of JREs.