# Can't install Oracle J2EE due to "An internal Error has occurred"

Tags: java, glassfish

I am trying to install Oracle JavaEE 6 SDK with Glassfish on Ubuntu 12.04 with Java SDK 7.
I have downloaded java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-linux-x64.sh already, but when I run it on terminal, the wizard appears, and after few steps, I get an Error Message Dialog:

> An internal Error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator... null.

And, the terminal is showing something like

> WARNING: Could not process a navigation event for  command=AC_NEXT
>   [Command=AC_NEXT Error=null ]

What can I do? How can I install J2EE/Glassfish under linux x64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your information: To install J2EE and Glassfish, we can use the Open Source version (Community Server): http://glassfish.java.net/
Just download and start it. It works!

Answer (score 0):

You can give ubuntu repositories a try. I installed openjdk 7 from the ubuntu repositories and believe me it's working great.

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```

Although you can install oracle's jdk; just issue the javac command on the terminal to see what packages are available.

I hope the information is helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to use openjava and see if I can install the J2EE on that environment, but I have installed the oracle jdk7 already on my machine and I don't want not remove it, since I installed Android and some other development tools.
The j2ee sdk stands for Java Enterprise Edition, and it give us a very rich platform (EJB, JSP, Servlets support) with the glassfish application server.